# Why Update using @Query in Spring Data Jpa requires @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, transactions, updates

I am new to spring boot. I use spring data jpa to deal with database. I have a method to update a table in the database using @Query. But when I try to update I get an exception of invalidDataAccessApiUsageException. when I tried it with @Transactional it gets updated successfully. Aren't updates a single operation so wouldn't it get committed automatically.

Comment: No. You don't want auto commits, who says that that update is the only operation being done? The actual tx boundary should be your service **not** your repository.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your point. I am kind of new to this. When I execute an update query in an SQL terminal. I dont use a transaction for update query but in case of spring boot JPA I cannot able to run it without transaction. can you suggest some links or posts regarding this.

Comment: You are still using a transaction but you don't know it. You cannot modify (insert, update, delete) stuff in a database without a transaction. You either have an implicit (auto-commit) or explicit transaction. You don't want auto-commit as that could lead to 10 seperate commits being done that should be a single one.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways in which transaction execute in SQL

Implicit -> One that means database, while running the write query(UPDATE, INSERT ....), create an isolation and then execute. If an error occurs, the isolation is discarded and no change will be written.

Explicit -> In this you explicitly specify the isolation start using BEGIN , discarding by ROLLBACK and finally writing by COMMIT

Initial versions of postgres (<7.4) had a configuration to called AUTOCOMMIT which when set off, will DISABLE implicit transactions. But this was disabled in 2003 since the databases were smart enough to discard isolations and not create inconsistencies.

In a nutshell at any point running following queries

```
UPDATE table_name WHERE id IN (....)
```

or

```
BEGIN
UPDATE table_name WHERE id IN (....)
COMMIT
```

are EXACTLY the same.

In JPA autocommit is now just a runtime validation for write queries.